# My form answers are not attaching to email

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I have wrote in scripting a simple question list, I need the responses to be returned in a txt file via email when the person hits submit.  The front end of the file works, the email creates but the form does not post. Can anyone help with this scripting please?

Coding listed below:

```
<form action="mailto:test@yahoo.com?subject=Test" id="form" method="post" name="form" >


<!-- PAGE HEADER -->

    <table bgcolor=#D1DEE5>
        <tr>
            <td  width="833px"align="center">
                <input class="title" name="Title" value="Customer Satisfaction Survey">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<!-- QUESTIONS -->
    <p>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p> Welcome message
                    <p> 

                    </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
        <table>
        <tr class="shaded">
            <td align="left">
                <p><b>Please tell us based on your experience, how satisfied you are with the following services:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="50px">Very satisfied</td>
            <td align="center" width="50px">Satisfied</td>
            <td align="center" width="50px">Dissatisfied</td>
            <td align="center" width="50px">Very Dissatisfied</td>
            <td align="center" width="50px">N/A</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td align="center" width="50px"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Very satisfied"></td>
            <td align="center" width="50px"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Satisfied"></td>
            <td align="center" width="50px"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Dissatisfied"></td>
            <td align="center" width="50px"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Very Dissatisfied"></td>
            <td align="center" width="50px"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="N/A"></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
    <table class="outlineTable" bgcolor=#D1DEE5>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" rowspan=5 width=500 style="vertical-align:top" style="padding-top:5px">
                <p><b>Please add comments to explain your answers</b>
                <br><textarea name="Comments10" id="Comments10" rows="7" cols="55"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                Month being scored
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="submitButton">
                <input class="name" name="Month">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                Name
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="submitButton">
                <input class="name" name="Name">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                Date
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="submitButton">
                <input class="name" name="Date">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="submitButton">
                <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Click here to submit results">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table bgcolor=#D1DEE5>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>    Many thanks for taking the time to complete this survey
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using `POST`, which doesn't work in mailto form submissions. only data passed in the url query string will be seen/read by the mail client.

Comment: I just put your code on my local system, This is adding all data in the mail

Comment: What are you seeing